# PHP iterate through cookies arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cookies

In my cakephp application I am trying to create a commenting functionality. So I use an ajax request to get the comments and then clone an html template and append it to the page:

```
//load comments
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/app/tasks/getComments',
                datatype: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) { // Add this line
                           xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
                        },
                data: {
                        task_id : "<?php echo $task->id; ?>"
                },
                success: function( data )
                {
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        //Clone the template
                        var item = $(template).clone();

                        document.cookie = 'photos['+i+']='+data[i].user.photo;
                        document.cookie = 'names['+i+']='+data[i].user.username;

                        //Find the  element
                        $(item).find('#comment_photo').html('<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["photos[$num]"])) {echo $this->Html->image($_COOKIE["photos[$num]"], ["class" => "avatar avatar-online", "alt" => $currentUser->username]); }  ?>');


                        $(item).find('#comment_username').html('<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["names[$num]"])) { echo $_COOKIE["names[$num]"]; }?>');

                        $(item).find('#comment_time').html(moment(data[i].created_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));

                        $(item).find('#comment_text').html(data[i].comment);
                        $(item).find('#comment_id').html(data[i].id);
                        //Append to the source
                        $('#target').append(item);


                    }

                }
            });
    });
```

In order to access the returned results in php I store them in cookie arrays (`photos[]`, `names[]`). How I can set and update the value of `$num` in order to iterate the arrays in every html code append? Is it possible to achieve what I want with this approach? Or I need a complete new one?

Comment: try to actually return a json object containing photos, names, etc. You'll see it's easier that way (and a lot more like what you'd expect an HTTP API to return).

Comment: @Oerd `data` is JSON, I don't actually get the solution you suggest...

Comment: with "...store them in cookie arrays..." do you mean that you return them in the $COOKIE object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was much simpler than I actually thought... I did it with JQuery like this:

```
.......

$(item).find('#comment_photo').prepend("<img src='/app/img/' class='avatar avatar-online'/>");
$(item).find('.avatar.avatar-online').prop('src', '/app/img/'+data[i].user.photo);
......
```